# Does python "file write()" method guarantee datas have been correctly written?

Tags: python

I'm new with python and I'm writting script to patch a file with something like:

```
def getPatchDatas(file):
  f = open(file,"rb")
  datas = f.read()
  f.close()
  return datas

f = open("myfile.bin","r+b")
f.seek(0xC020)
f.write(getPatchDatas("mypatch.bin"))
f.close()
```

I would like to be sure the patch as been applied correctly.
So, if no error / exception is raised, does it mean I'm 100% sure the patch has been correctly written?

Or is it better to double check with something like:

```
f = open("myfile.bin","rb")
f.seek(0xC020)
if not f.read(0x20) == getPatchDatas("mypatch.bin"):
  print "Patch not applied correctly!"
f.close()
```

??
Thanks.

Comment: What in life is 100%.  If your tolerance for error is 0% then maybe you should check it.  You may want to work with files using the ```with``` keyword - [```with open('workfile', 'r') as f:```](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects). And you may want to write your own context manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't, but roughly it does. It depends how much it matters.

Anything could go wrong - it could be a consumer hard disk which lies to the operating system about when it has finished writing data to disk. It could be corrupted in memory and that corrupt version gets written to disk, or it could be corrupted inside the disk during writing by electrical or physical problems.

It could be intercepted by kernel modules on Linux, filter drivers on Windows or a FUSE filesystem provider which doesn't actually support writing but pretends it does, meaning nothing was written.

It could be screwed up by a corrupted Python install where exceptions don't work or were deliberately hacked out of it, or file objects monkeypatched, or accidentally run in an uncommon implementation of Python which fakes supporting files but is otherwise identical.

These kinds of reasons are why servers have server class hardware with higher tolerances to temperature and electrical variation, error checking and correcting memory (ECC), RAID controller battery backups, ZFS checksumming filesystem, Uninterruptable Power Supplies, and so on.

But, as far as normal people and low risk things go - if it's written without error, it's as good as written. Double-checking makes sense - especially as it's that easy. It's nice to know if something has failed.

Comment: Thanks. So I'll keep this check. I'll maybe have a look on a hash check to. If quicker.

Answer (score 0):

In single process, it is.

In multi processes(e.g. One process is writing and another is reading. Even you ensure it'll only read after call "write", the "write" need some time to finish), you may need a [filelock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filelock/).